# Getting Missing 1 invocation to... in

Tags: java, spring-boot, jmockit

I have a test that is testing a Spring @Service class. This service class autowires in a dao @Repository. The dao also autowires in a class to provide extra functionality. I would like to mock the calls in the dao so I have something like so:

```
@DisplayName("Tests for ...")
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
public class MyServiceTest
{
    @Injectable
    TheRepository myDao;

    @Tested(fullyInitialized = true)
    TheService myServiceUnderTest;

    @Nested
    @Tag("...")
    @DisplayName("Tests for method: ...")
    class TestClassContainer {
        @Test
        public void test1() {
            IAnalysisDataScenario data = new CommonAnalysisDataScenario();
            new Expectations() {{
                myDao.nameExists(anyString); result = data.mockedNameExists();
                ...
            }};

            Map<String, Object> result = myServiceUnderTest.getAnalysis(data.getName(),data.getId());
            assertTrue(!result.isEmpty());
        }
    }
}
```

The call to getAnalysis in the service calls the dao method nameExists which I want to return the result from mockedNameExists in the Expectations block but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This is what I see when I run the test:

Missing 1 invocation to:
...dao.impl.TheRepository#nameExists(any String)
on mock instance: ...dao.impl.TheRepository@61230f6a

Caused by: Missing invocations
at ...dao.impl.TheRepository.nameExists(TheRepository.java)

Answer (score 2):

I see what the issue is in this case. The error message now makes sense. In this particular test, the method that is missing the invocation is not actually called because of the code path the test takes based on the the parameters. So the Expectations block must only contain mocking behavior for code that actually WILL BE EXECUTED. Now I understand